# Referenceing Piped Element's Parent

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write some PowerShell to go through a folder and preform different operations depending on the file name.  The issue I'm having is when I use a Switch Case $_ only contains the Base Name (see below).  Is there a way to access it's parent element? I need to get Full Path of the file. I saw somewhere that you could $_.Parent.FullPath, but that seems to not be correct.

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Folder\" -Filter "*.xls" | ForEach-Object {
    switch -Wildcard ($_.BaseName){
       "*test1*" {
            Write-Host "Test1"
            Write-Host $_.Parent.FullName
       }
       "*test2*" {
            Write-Host "Test2"
            Write-Host $_.Parent.FullName
       }
       "*tets3*" {
            Write-Host "Test3"
            Write-Host $_.Parent.FullName
       }
    }
}
```

I know if I changed from a Swtich Case to IF statements that I would have access to the FullName.

Comment: You are switching on basename so the inner `$_` is just that. Save the outer `$_` in another variable if you want to use that in the inner block.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell XML: Switch vs if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081667/powershell-xml-switch-vs-if)

Comment: You can switch on Fullname, and then use Split-Path to get the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in the Switch statement, you're basically within a new pipeline, so you lose your reference to the parent object.

**Unless** you stored that object elsewhere.  For instance, before your Switch statement, I added `$file = $_` to store a reference to the current object within $file.  When I run it now, this is what I see:

```
$file = $_ 
    switch -Wildcard ($_.BaseName){
       "*test1*" {
            Write-Host "Test1"
            Write-Host $file.FullName}
[...]

>Test1
C:\temp\Test1.txt
Test12
C:\temp\Test12.txt
Test100
C:\temp\Test100.txt
```

You can now reference the current object again by using $file and picking any of its properties.  I hope this puts you on the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't even look at the question until just now. You have an accepted answer, and I'm happy that you were able to get it worked out, but I wanted to add another option...

You can switch on the object as a whole and just validate on scriptblocks, that way you have access to the entire fileinfo object and not just the basename property:

```
Switch((Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Folder\" -Filter "*.xls")){
    {$_.BaseName -like "*Test1*"} {"Test1";$_.FullName}
    {$_.BaseName -like "*Test2*"} {"Test2";$_.FullName}
    {$_.BaseName -like "*Test3*"} {"Test3";$_.FullName}
}
```

Alternatively you could run a RegEx match in a Where statement and capture the things you are looking for, then return `$Matches[1]` and the `FullName` property in a `ForEach` loop:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Folder\" -Filter "*.xls" | Where{$_.basename -match "(test1|test2|test3)"} | ForEach{$Matches[1];$_.FullName}
```

Either of these will provide you with your desired output. Neither of them directly answer your question of how to access the parent item, but they are fairly solid ways to avoid having to assign it to a variable and then reference that variable later.